# Where is index.yaml imported in Google App Engine for Golang?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Playing with Bookshelf tutorial and the Auth package.

The ListBooksCreatedBy query is failing with this error:

```
could not list books: datastoredb: could not list books: rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition desc = no matching index found. recommended index is:   
- kind: Book   
  properties:   
  - name: CreatedByID   
  - name: Title
```

However, index.yaml does exist and is in the same directory as app.yaml :
index YAML content:

```
indexes:   

# This index enables filtering by "CreatedByID" and sort by "Title".   
- kind: Book   
  properties:   
  - name: CreatedByID   
    direction: asc   
  - name: Title   
    direction: asc
```

Why would the index not be imported?

Where in the Golang App Engine code is the index.yaml imported?

I searched the src and found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index.yaml` file is not intended to be imported/used in your application code, it is intended to be deployed to the Datastore service (separately/independently from your app deployments!) to configure its indexing activities. From [Updating indexes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/indexconfig#updating_indexes):

> You upload your `index.yaml` configuration file to Cloud Datastore
>   with the gcloud command. If the `index.yaml` file defines any indexes
>   that don't exist in Cloud Datastore, those new indexes are built.
>
> It can take a while for Cloud Datastore to create all the indexes and
>   therefore, those indexes won't be immediately available to App Engine.
>   If your app is already configured to receive traffic, then exceptions
>   can occur for queries that require an index that is still in the
>   process of being built.
>
> To avoid exceptions, you must allow time for all the indexes to build.

Only after proper deployment and, if needed, the completion of the index update operation (i.e. the index reaches the `Serving` state) the app's queries needing that index can work.

The `index.yaml` file is also used by the local development server in its datastore emulation. By default it automatically updates the file with the necessary indexes for the queries it encounters, but the file isn't automatically deployed to the Datastore. But you can disable this behaviour using the `--require_indexes` option. From [Local Development Server Options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/local-devserver-command):

> `--require_indexes=yes|no`
>
> Disables automatic generation of entries in the `index.yaml` file.
>   Instead, when the application makes a query that requires that its
>   index be defined in the file and the index definition is not found, an
>   exception will be raised, similar to what would happen when running on
>   App Engine. The default value is `no`.

Comment: I've searched ~/google-cloud-sdk for the error message, "no matching index found" but could not find it. I could find files the created index.yaml but not where is was imported into the local dev server.

Comment: You won't see the error message - the dev server automatically updates the index.yaml file and takes the update into consideration. I don't think there is a message about doing so, or at least I didn't notice it. See also my answer update.

Comment: Wouldn't there have to be a string with the error message within the python source code for the local Server to throw it? If not, where would the error message be defined?

Comment: Hm, not sure. You could start from the `--require_indexes` optional argument and follow the trail.