# Import data to a GCP Project's App Engine Search from another GCP Project's App Engine Search

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We are planning on migrating from google-datastore to google-firestore. But before we do so on our live project we need to test that the process goes smoothly, so we have created a new project to perform the overall migration process.

We have successfully imported data from our "Datastore" project to our "Firestore in Datastore mode" project, but we are unable to find any guide on how to import App Engine Search data (including all namespaces and indexes) from our existing GCP Project to the new one.
We have followed the process from this official guide https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/upgrade-to-firestore#testing_an_existing_application
P.S.: Both the projects are in different organization too (if that helps).

**Update 18 Nov 2019**
Please refer to the image attached: the one in green boxes is done, this question is about the ones in red boxes
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way to index Firestore in datastore mode is with `index.yaml` files. The information about this file can be found in this link [1].

The `index.yaml` configuration file is required for composite indexes, since single-property indexes are already built in.
A good answer from this site providing more information about this file can be found in this other link [2].

To configure the indexes you need to upload them using the command-line `gcloud` tool.

```
gcloud datastore indexes create INDEX_FILE
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444904/6003934

Comment: We appreciate your help. This is exactly how we imported the data in "datastore". What we are looking for is how do we import data from Google App Engine Search. Please refer to the image attached I've updated the question with the image: the one in green boxes is done (exactly the way you suggested), this question is about the ones in red boxes.

Comment: hey @AliZaidi, You cannot export Search API indexes, so you cannot import Search API data to Firestore.